# Is it considered as impolite to say, what's up when someone asks you to help

Tags: phrase-meaning, politeness

I was in a fashion shop for some clothing, and a man in the same shop suddenly came to ask me if I could help him fill in a short questionnaire.
Because I didn't expect such thing to happen in a fashion shop, I was surprised and said this without thinking:

> what's up

Is it impolite to say what's up when someone asks you to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't think it's impolite. For instance:

"Excuse me, can you help me please?"

"Sure - what's up?" - seems like a polite enough way to ask what the problem is, although certainly very informal.

But as a response to someone asking you to fill out a questionnaire, it doesn't seem to make much sense. It seems like your response just needed to be yes or no at this point.

Comment: I agree that it's a normal, polite, very informal response.  I think it's reasonably sensible as a response, though - "what's up?" can mean something like "What's going on?" or "What is the situation?" so it's reasonable as a kind of *What's the situation with this questionnaire?*

Answer (score 0):

If I were greeted by anyone with "What's up?" I would immediately suspect the interrogator of hostile intent.
It reeks of suspicion and hostility, or at least purveys the notion that the interrogator assumes the upper hand or a position of superiority.
It may be fashionable and in vogue, but it is definitely not friendly.
I would be tempted to respond with "Mind your own damned business!"
Sadly a similar form, also unfriendly, used to be in fashion, was, "What's the problem?" whenever approaching the likes of a customer service situation, also nasty and unnecessary and assumes a superior status.
Both convey a gross lack of respect and are not acceptable.

Comment: While they may ‘both convey a gross lack of respect’ in a very formal context, that’s certainly not true in an informal one.